# Ember app has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I was trying to use my api and I have a function on ember app to login but when the login action is trigerred I receive a message below. What is the reason I am receiving this error?

```
login:1 Access to fetch at 'https://app-dev.some-url.com.au/api/login' from origin
'http://localhost:4099' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch 
the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API server isn’t configured to accept requests that come from a web application on another origin. Some options:

1. Configure your API to serve the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header
   on the `OPTIONS` request that the browser makes to test this. It
   could be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if you’re lazy or can’t
   know in advance what origins people will be coming from. It’s hard
   to be more specific about this without knowing details of your API.
2. Use Ember CLI’s [API
   proxying](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/appendix/dev-tools/#proxyingnetworkrequests)
   feature to bypass the need for CORS. This is for development mode
   only, though. You’d need a similar solution in production where
   Ember CLI’s development server isn’t present.